# Can't join 3 tables in mysql to link user ID

Tags: php, mysql

I am thinking maybe this isn't possible, but I want to join 3 tables at the ID (users) column, which all 3 tables have. Been at it for days now. This may be a bit confusing for anyone willing to help though...

The table architecture and table explanations are:

wp_users (ID, display_name)  This is the users table

stories (ID, SID)     This table stores the story name and who started it

writing (ID, SID, WID, text)    This table stores the all the pieces of writing that different authors add to the SID, so there can be multiple rows of SID here, each with different user ID. ID is the user and matches the ID values in the other tables. WID is the pieces of writing for each SID.

Each story ID (SID) has multiple records in the writing table, each with a different writing ID. The stories table only has one SID and one ID--the person who started the story. My code is only giving the display_name based on the ID in this stories table (the person who started the story). I need it to show the display names for each piece of writing added by others for that SID, which are stored writing table.

The code currently works except that it gives the same author (display_name) for all pieces of writing stored in the writing table, even though there are different authors for each writing piece (WID).

The problem is, as soon as I try to add another join such as join wp_users on writing.ID = wp_users.ID I get no results for any variables. If I do not try to join this third table at ID, the code works, but it will only display

```
SELECT wp_users.ID, wp_users.display_name,
stories.ID, stories.SID, stories.story_name, stories.category,
writing.ID, writing.text, writing.approved
FROM stories
JOIN wp_users ON stories.ID = wp_users.ID
JOIN writing ON stories.SID = writing.SID
WHERE (stories.SID = $the_SID) AND (writing.approved = 'Y')
");

<?php 
foreach ($results as $result) {
echo "<br>" . "Author: " . $result->display_name . "<br>" . $result->text . "<br>";
```

Could part of the problem be that the name ID cannot be the same for all 3 tables? Is it even possible to join 3 tables on ID? Would greatly appreciate any help...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sure it's possible to `JOIN` as many tables as you want. It just depends what results you're after. Also, I think you're after `LEFT JOIN` for these queries.

If your "main select" is going to be the `writing` table, then try something like:

```
SELECT
    wp_users.ID,
    wp_users.display_name,
    stories.ID,
    stories.SID,
    stories.story_name,
    stories.category,
    writing.ID,
    writing.text,
    writing.approved
FROM writing
    LEFT JOIN stories on writing.SID = stories.SID
    LEFT JOIN wp_users ON writing.ID = wp_users.ID
WHERE (stories.SID = $the_SID) AND (writing.approved = 'Y')
```

Comment: Interesting. But same results. From doing a var_dump() on $results I see the same thing....it does return all the records for each piece of writing and it even returning the correct user ID for each, but it still will not display the correct author name (display_name) in the echo. It keeps displaying the same author name for all the records, which is the user name of the person who started the story. That is, it seems to still be returning the display name for the ID passed from stories.ID and not the user name from writing.ID

Comment: I think you just answered your own question. Try changing the line `LEFT JOIN wp_users ON stories.ID = wp_user.ID` to `LEFT JOIN wp_users ON writing.ID = wp_user.ID`. I've edited my answer

Comment: YOU ROCK!!!!! Many thanks! That's it! I have had a few people who know there stuff and couldn't figure this one out. a great many thanks!!!

Comment: No worries. Check out some good resources and educate yourself on `JOIN`s and how they work, how they differ, and when to use each type. This is a good visual guide: http://blog.codinghorror.com/a-visual-explanation-of-sql-joins/